# How to copy a string to another string in python

Tags: python, string, copy

I have two strings, `s1` and `s2`, and I need to find if there are letters in common in both of them and make it double for example:

```
s1 = "Hello World"
s2 = "lo"
output = "Helllloo Woorlld"
```

My code:

```
s2="lo"
s1="Hello World"

    def Str_dup(s1,s2):
        s3=str()
        d=dict()
        for i in s2:
            d[i]=True
            print i
            w=0
        for w in range(len(s1)):
            if d[s1[w]]:
                s3[w]=s3[w]+s1[w]
            else :
                s3[w]=s1[w]
        return s3
    Str_dup(s1,s2)
```

I get an error on:

```
    if d[s2[w]]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: `s1` is longer than `s2`, so obviously `w` is too big sometimes to get `s2[w]`. Also you can't modify a string as in `s3[w]=...`. You need to make a list of characters and then combine them into a string with `''.join(list_of_chars)`.

Comment: *"string index out of the range"*?! Please just copy and paste the literal text, it makes it far less likely you'll provide inaccurate information.

Comment: thnx a lot it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be so much easier to treat the strings as lists of characters and use list comprehension to construct the output string:

```
output = ''.join([c*2 if c in s2 else c for c in s1])
```